# Symfony2: How to set the locale manually?

Tags: php, symfony

Please, could you help me with this problem? 
However I set through link the _locale in symfony2 to english, it still takes the text in czech language and I don´t know, how to solve it. 
Please, help

**$locale** I get from session like this:

```
       $locale = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('_locale');
```

Here is file which contains repository method.
http://pastebin.com/zbcvXttk

EDIT:
After I changed the way how I get locale from previous to this:

```
   $locale = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('_locale');
   $this->get('gedmo.listener.translatable')->setTranslatableLocale($locale);
```

It works, but there is problem, that it wrotes me for the first time I visit web this error:

> Locale or language cannot be empty and must be set through Listener or Entity

I´m trying to find out some help on the net but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this?

```
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->set('_locale', 'en');
```

Comment: I hope that yes. Thank you very much